# Use Sed to replace a string with another string obtained from a regex

Tags: regex, sed

I want to replace a string (in the example the word Linux) with whatever is between the #'s on the first line.

So I want to turn:

```
#Windows#
1. Linux Sysadmin, Linux Scripting etc.
2. Databases - Oracle, mySQL etc.
3. Security (Firewall, Network, Online Security etc)
4. Storage in Linux
5. Productivity (Too many technologies to explore, not much time available)
```

into:

```
1. Windows Sysadmin, Windows Scripting etc.
2. Databases - Oracle, mySQL etc.
3. Security (Firewall, Network, Online Security etc)
4. Storage in Windows
5. Productivity (Too many technologies to explore, not much time available)
```

or

```
#Solaris#
1. Linux Sysadmin, Linux Scripting etc.
2. Databases - Oracle, mySQL etc.
3. Security (Firewall, Network, Online Security etc)
4. Storage in Linux
5. Productivity (Too many technologies to explore, not much time available)
```

into:

```
1. Solaris Sysadmin, Solaris Scripting etc.
2. Databases - Oracle, mySQL etc.
3. Security (Firewall, Network, Online Security etc)
4. Storage in Solaris
5. Productivity (Too many technologies to explore, not much time available)
```

Just using sed.
I've got as far as:
sed '
/^#[a-zA-Z ]*/{
h
d
}
/Linux/ G'

I think what I need to do is is run a regular expression using the hold buffer as the replacement pattern which I guess would look like `s/Linux/g` but I can't find a way to do this.
Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an sed solution:

```
sed '
/^#.*#$/{                      # if replacement text is matchd
s/#//g                           # remove all pound chars
h                                # copy pattern space to hold space
d                                # delete pattern space and start over
}                              # end if
:a                             # create label "a"
G                              # append hold to pattern
s/Linux\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/    # replace Linux with contents of hold space
ta                             # if above replacement succeeded, go to "a"
s/\n.*//                       # remove replacement text and print pattern space
' file.txt
```

One-liner if you can use `;` to separate commands:

```
sed '/^#.*#$/{s/#//g;h;d};:a;G;s/Linux\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/;ta;s/\n.*//' file.txt
```

Comment: Interesting, I had thought that without the `-n` switch it was resulting in an extra newline at the beginning of the output, but I just tested it again the output looked correct.  Just edited my answer to remove it.

Answer (score 3):

You will be better off using awk. Consider this script:

```
awk '/^#/ {gsub("#", "", $0); txt=$0} {gsub("Linux", txt, $0); print}' file.txt
```

Comment: I want to do this in the context of an apache mod_sed directive, there's no performant way that I'm aware of to run apache output through awk.